# NotWritableException Can't write image data to path on heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am trying to save my image data to a folder. It works fine on my localhost but when i moved it to heroku it gives me this error

```
NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path (https://arcane-peak- 
34431.herokuapp.com/public/images/categories/1527155055.jpg)
```

Here is my code.

```
$image = $request->file('image');
    $imagename = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $imagename = time().'.'.$imagename;

    $destinationPath = URL::to('public/images/restaurants');
    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

    $img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename);

    $destinationPath = URL::to('public/images/restaurants');

    $image->move($destinationPath, $imagename);
```

What am i doing wrong? And also on my local machine it is the uploaded image that is getting saved but i want my resized image to be saved.Any help would be a life saver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bigger issue is that even if you get your image to save it will disappear. Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) (bold added):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and **any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.**

[Heroku recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) storing user uploads using a third-party service like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Comment: You didn't answer the question about the error. I'm getting the same Exception and I know it's an ephemeral filesystem. That doesn't fix the issue. Do you have any suggestion for the causes of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `git push heroku main` command excludes the image destination from being uploaded because it was empty. So in this case **public/images/categories** will not exist in the heroku app server.

You can run `heroku run bash -a <APP_NAME>` to check the app folder if the **public/images/categories** does exist online or not.

To prevent the error from future occurrence, you can add an empty index.php file in the folder before you run `git push`, this will make sure the folder gets uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Image::make($image)->save('images/restaurants/' . $imagename);
```

This works for me